# Time Complexity of a while loop that adds a variable that increases by 1 each iteration

Tags: data-structures, while-loop, time-complexity, big-o

The code I am trying to find the time complexity of is

```
int i=1,s=1;
while (s<=n)
    i++
    s+=i;
    print("*")
```

I traced it with n = 10 and, if I'm doing it correctly, this runs 4 times for this instance. I cannot figure out what the general complexity would be, I keep thinking log base2(n) but this doesn't exactly work. Would really like to know how to find this or if it is just some simple equation I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Gaussian summation formula will help you: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .. + n = ((n + 1)*n)/n = (n² + n) / 2`. The formula calculates the sum of the first `n` natural numbers.

Comment: so according to this it would run 55 times if n=10. for while loops do you count each individual action? I thought you just counted how many times the loop ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the [Gaussian summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%E2%8B%AF) which calculates the sum of the first `k` natural numbers with `k` being a natural number:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .. + k = ((k + 1)*k)/k = (k² + k) / 2
```

e.g. for `k = 4`:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = ((4 + 1)*4) / 2 = (5 * 4) / 2 = 20 / 4 = 10
```

If you look at your code you will see that `s` is exactly that sum.

The `while` loop runs till `s <= n`. `s` can be described by above formula as `i` is 1, then `i = 2`, then `i = 3` and so on. So you can substitute `s` with above formula and get `(i² + i) / 2 <= n`. You know `n = 10`.

Therefore:

`(i² + i) / 2 <= 10` <=>

`i² + i <= 20` <=>

`i² + i - 20 <= 0`

Solve that (e.g. using "midnight formula" as we call it in Germany) and you get the solutions `i <= 4` and `i <= -5`. `i <= -5` obviously does not make sense in your example so `4` will be your solution.

You can generalize and approximate that (solve the quadratic equation `i² + i - n <= 0`) following the rules of [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and you will have your runtime which will be `O(n^1/2)` or `Theta(n^1/2)` to be exact.

Comment: Thank you this all makes sense to me! I am not seeing how I can generalize it in terms of n though. I originally thought replace i with n but that would give me 90 not 4 if I were to use n = 10.

Comment: You need to continue with `(i² + i) / 2 <= n`. Following the rules of big-O notation you will be able to ignore constants, constant factors etc. . Have a look at [Yves Doust`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73653993/17487348) below as he/ she's gone ahead and done that.

Answer (score 1):

`i` follows an arithmetic progression of initial term `1` and common difference `1`. `s` is the prefix sum of `i` (values `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, ...`). The general term is `i(i+1)/2`.

Now the loop runs as long as `s≤n`. We obtain the corresponding `i` by solving

```
i(i+1)/2 = n
```

and taking the integer part,

```
i = floor(√(2n+1/4) - 1/2).
```

As `i` represents the number of iterations of the loop, the complexity is of order `Θ(√n)`.

Comment: I cannot seem to follow how you solved for i here. Is there any way you can walk through how you got that equation?

Comment: @SierraWalker: it is a quadratic equation.